# Dryad appeared, but hasn't settled in

Tags: terraria

I'm finally giving Terraria a go, and am quite enjoying it.

I recently killed the Eye of Cthulu, and got the notification that the Dryad has entered the world.

Now, I had housing already available for her (I went with a tall apartment style building for NPCs), and the lower levels are already populated.  However, its been probably at least a few days of playing and she still hasn't settled in a room.

Thinking the room was too high, I built another one on the ground level to the necessary specifications, as I understand them, however she still has not appeared.

Is there any special necessity for the Dryad to settle in?

Comment: there is a mode (I havent played in so long so I don't remember how to access it) that shows what residents are in rooms (signified by flags). Go to that mode and see what's up. It will also tell you which areas are livable (all NPCs require the same things)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Dryad, doesn't have any other special requirements other than the base ones required to unlock her in the first place. If you have already unlocked the Dryad and have a proper house, she should soon settle in that particular house. Unless of course, she moved into another home.

As JLaBella has said, try checking if those homes are properly built to support NPCs. You can do so by accessing the Housing Menu. Specifically, click the house icon on the inventory screen, choose the "?" housing query mark, and then click anywhere inside the houses in question. That'll tell you whether the home is suitable, or what specifically it's missing.

You may also use this menu to determine where NPCs are currently living, as well as change which NPCs live where.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the pointer on the menu option...I never even noticed the little house!

Answer (score 6):

The dryad has no specific housing requirements above and beyond the normal npc requirement of a house.

My guess is you have an outpost somewhere that qualifies as a house, and the dryad has moved in there.  You can use the housing menu to assign the dryad to the house you would like her to live in, and she will move from wherever she is at, to the new digs.